# Cleaning column data in R

Tags: r

Hi I wrote this function to clean up my data in R:

```
periodCleanse <- function(x) {
    if (x == ""){
        return ("");
    }
    else if (substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)) == "M"){
        return(30*as.numeric(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1)));
    }
    else if (substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)) == "Y"){
        return(365*as.numeric(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1)));
    }
    else if (substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)) == "D"){
        return (as.numeric(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1)));
    }
}
```

My df looks something like this:

```
period
3M
5Y

1D
7M
```

I want to call

```
df$period <- periodCleanse(df$period))
```

but I am getting:

```
Warning message:
In if (x == "") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and nothing happens. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a vectorized function that will both save you from writing endless `if` `else` and running it in a loop (`sapply`)

```
periodCleanse2 <- function(x){
  matchDat <- data.frame(A = c("M", "Y", "D"), B = c(30, 365, 1)) # You can take that part out of the function for improving speed
  indx <- gsub("\\d", "", x)
  indx2 <- as.numeric(gsub("[A-Z]", "", x))
  matchDat$B[match(indx, matchDat$A)] * indx2
}

periodCleanse2(df$period)
## [1]   90 1825   NA    1  210
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function accepts a vector (the data frame's column) but only returns one value. You can get around this by `apply`ing your function to every element of the vector: `sapply(df$period, periodCleanse)`. Note that `nchar` only works if your column is a character vector and not a factor.

The warning is triggered because you're taking a vector of booleans (from `x == ""`) and using it in an `if` condition; R will only use the first element, and generates a warning because it might not be what you want. As an alternative, you can chain multiple `ifelse` calls as it's vectorised, but this can become unwieldy for more than a few conditions.